# How to change company name in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

When I log into iTunes Connect, the page header says

> [iTunes Connect logo] Torben Gundtofte-Bruun, Torben Gundtofte-Bruun [Sign out button]

**Why is my name listed twice?** I guess one of the fields should have been my company name, right? **How do I change this?**

Comment: You have to send an email to apple asking them to change your company name, along with a certificate of incorporation and a letter saying that you have authority to act on behalf of the company.

Comment: Why a close vote? Is there another SE site where this question is better placed? I think my question is valid according to the FAQ, and the above comment would be a great answer - thanks @jacktheripper!

Comment: No problem, I'll post it now!

Comment: Might I also recommend registering for the following Stack Exchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field inside iTunes Connect that you are referencing would typically show a user and company name in the following format:

> Joe Bloggs, Example Corp

As you are an individual that registered for a developer account and not as a company, your name is diplayed twice in the field above.

If you wish to change this to the name of a company, you need to contact Apple (telephone is best for an immediate response and to kickstart the "iOS Developer Program Company Assignment" process) and tell them this.

You'll receive an email with the above title where you can login online and provide the relevant information, which will include a faxed copy of the company's ceritificate of incorporation and (sometimes) a company letterhead with some more info that Apple may or may not request.

Find your country's contact number here:

https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have to send an email to Apple developer support asking them to change your company name, along with a certificate of incorporation and a letter saying that you have authority to act on behalf of the company.